# Getting ORA-01858 error while inserting time stamp

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, oracle12c

My timestamp format in front end is like this

```
2020-7-23 14:36:43. 132000000
```

My timestamp in oracle db is like this

```
23-07-20 02:36:43.132000000 PM
```

I have changed the time format like below

```
private String OracleTsString(String createdDate)  {
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat=null;
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = null;
        try {
        
          inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
          Date date;
          date = inputFormat.parse(createdDate);
           outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS aa");
        
        }
   //Exception Handling
```

But when I try to insert the string into database , I am getting  ****ORA-01858**: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected**

Below is my  query

```
jdbcTemplate.update(query, 
                editSftpBean.getSftpName(),
                editSftpBean.getIp_address(),
                editSftpBean.getPort_number(),
                editSftpBean.getUserName(),
                editSftpBean.getAuthentication(),
                oracleTs//My converted string
);
```

insert query::

```
 INSERT INTO tabl_two (SFTP_NAME, IP_ADDRESS, PORT_NUMBER, USER_NAME, AUTH_TYPE,CREATED_DATE ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why does the `INSERT` name 6 column, only have 5 parameter markers, but use 8 values in the `update()` call? Those three numbers should be the same.

Comment: Q: Is the space after "seconds" a typo: `2020-7-23 14:36:43. 132000000`?  More importantly, the #/columns doesn't seem to match the #/placeholders in your insert and doesn't match the #/parameters in your update()

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a `String` to insert a date/time value into the database, use a [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

```java
private static Timestamp parseTsString(String createdDate) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-M-d H:mm:ss")
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .toFormatter();
    return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(createdDate, fmt));
}
```

Comment: I followed your steps . But the timestamps are being populated wrongly. When I first fetched from  backend the timestamp, it was 30-07-20 10:59:35.372000000 AM
When I follwed the steps suggested by you and inserted in a new row it is now
03-08-20 06:19:35.000000000 PM

Comment: @Mr.X Why would timestamp be `30-07-20 10:59:35.372000000 AM`? That is not how a `java.sql.Timestamp` or a `java.util.Date` presents themselves. Seems you're fetching from backend incorrectly. And what is the string value of the `createdDate` parameter when you call this method? From the question, I assumed it was a string like `2020-07-30 10:59:35.372000000` coming from the UI frontend.

Comment: I just run the code giving a plain string directly in the same format.It is the output is wrong this time also

Comment: @Mr.X Oh right, `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support 9 fractional digits, besides we shouldn't be using that old flawed class anyway. Answer fixed.